# Error 403:Authentication Failed in sso

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

[I have created bluemix sso and enabled cloud directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irwSM.jpg)
I have configured web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

    <display-name>SSOTestPoject</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>

    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>UserCollection</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>any-authenticated</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>


</web-app>
```

I have configured  ibm-application-bnd.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<application-bnd
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">

    <security-role name="any-authenticated">
        <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
    </security-role>
</application-bnd>
```

After pushing the application in bluemix I am able to access the application it is redirecting to login page[SSO Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZOwV.jpg).

After login instead of taking to application it is throwing error. **Error 403:Authentication Failed**

Comment: Was the user/password correct? Where is SSO looking up the user/password info?

Comment: user/password is correct. It is looking in to cloud directory for user/password.

Comment: Do you mean that you are UNable to access the application?

Comment: yes, I am not able to access the application.